# Relacionamento 1:1

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, relacionamento

Estou com problemas no relacionamento das minhas tabelas **produtos e estoque.** A tabela estoque é responsável por armazenar a quantidade de cada item da tabela produtos e a data de quando o produto entrou em estoque. Cada item da tabela produtos só pode ser cadastrado uma vez na tabela estoque. Então estava utilizando a seguinte estrutura:

```
create table produtos(
id_produto int unsigned auto_increment not null,
marca int unsigned not null,
categoria int unsigned not null,
nome varchar(100) not null,
valor double not null,
descricao varchar(250) not null,
tamanho varchar(2),
cor varchar(15),
sexo varchar(1),
constraint pk_produto primary key (id_produto),
constraint fk_marca foreign key (marca) references marcas(id_marca),
constraint fk_categoria foreign key(categoria) references categorias(id_categoria)
);

create table estoque(
id_estoque int unsigned auto_increment not null,
produto int unsigned not null unique,
qtd int unsigned not null,
datarep date not null,
constraint pk_estoque primary key(id_estoque),
constraint fk_produto foreign key(produto) references produtos(id_produto)
);
```

O problema é que dessa forma, eu consigo cadastrar o mesmo produto várias vezes no estoque. Então, eu acabei pensando em algumas alternativas:

- Criar um campo **unique** não nulo para identificar os produtos na tabela estoque, e consequentemente impedir que o produto com o mesmo código seja cadastrado.
- Utilizar a chave estrangeria produto como chave primária da tabela estoque, mas tenho minhas dúvidas se isso seria uma boa prática.
- Juntar a tabela estoque na tabela produto através dos atributos quantidade e data_reposição, por exemplo. Nesse caso, eu precisaria atualizar a tabela a cada compra e chegada de um novo estoque.

Qual seria a melhor opção para esse caso? Se nenhuma delas forem uma boa prática, o que eu poderia fazer?
obs: Estou utilizando o mysql.

Comment: 1... O id já seria seu campo unique, pode utilizar uma função de hash baseada no id pra gerar um hash único pra cada produto. 2... Com isso você impediria que houvesse mais do mesmo produto cadastrado no estoque, sinceramente não vejo muito mal, a não ser que queira manter um histórico de quando o produto entrou e quando acabou, nesse caso seria legar ter um campo criado_em, e quando o produto no estoque acabasse atualizasse um campo finalizado_em com o timestamp atual., na próxima reposição criasse uma nova linha na tabela.

Comment: Se você já tem a `constraint fk_produto foreign key(produto) references produtos(id_produto)` não vejo muito sentido em ainda ter `produto int unsigned not null unique,`

Comment: Olá, Marcelo. Você teria um exemplo de utilização dessa hash? Acredito que eu precisaria de campo para gerar e armazenar essa hash, correto? Apesar de ter essa constraint, eu ainda consigo cadastrar o mesmo produto no estoque mais de uma vez, por isso adicionei esse unique pra ver como ficaria, mas acabei não testando.

Comment: Pode procurar por algo dentro do próprio mysql, ou usar alguma ferramenta externa, quando for criado seu registro, pegar o `last_id_insert` e usar [essa](http://hashids.org/) biblioteca por exemplo, para gerar um hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu caso, que o relacionamento das tabelas é 1 pra 1, não vejo muito sentido em serem implementadas separadas. Poderia ficar tudo numa tabela só:

```
Produtos (id[PK], marca, categoria,..., qtd_estoque, data_estoque)
```

Mas se você for fazer gestão dos itens individuais de cada Produto no estoque, então você poderia ter a tabela de estoque dos itens e a quantidade de produtos no estoque poderia ser computado da própria tabela somando os itens daquele produto. Exemplo de uma tabela de estoque para itens:

```
Estoque (id[PK], id_produto[FK], data_inclusao)
```

Comment: Também pensei nisso, mas não teria problema pelo fato do registro estar sendo sempre atualizado em caso de uma venda?

Comment: Mas qual seria o problema?

Comment: Eu pensei que pudesse haver algum problema com fato de estar sempre atualizando um registro dessa tabela, viajei aqui. Bom, agora que você citou, essa segunda opção parece ser melhor, imagino que assim eu conseguiria ter um relatório com a quantidade de estoque e etc, mas isso transformaria minha tabela em um relacionamento um para muitos, correto?

Comment: Não haveria problemas em atualizar um registro constantemente​. Banco de Dados é feito pra isso, rs. Sim, seu relacionamento na segunda opção seria 1 para muitos.

Comment: Pois é. rs. Amigo, acho que estou chegando no banco ideal, mas ainda tenho mais uma dúvida, se não se importar. Essa segunda opção é a melhor pelo fato de eu poder manipular o estoque, ver quando entrou, quando acabou e etc, mas como ficaria a questão da quantidade? Acredito que eu vá precisar desse campo para identificar quantos itens chegaram, mas qual seria a maneira ideal? Ter a quantidade na própria tabela estoque? ou em ambas as tabelas?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ESTOQUE WHERE ID_PRODUTO = 1

Comment: Com isso você soma todos os itens em estoque do produto com id 1

Comment: Valeu, Márcio. Irei fazer isso!